# sending query with get request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, fuseki

I want to send a query (body) with the get request, I know it's not making sense but I want to execute the get query at the other endpoint(which is Fuseki server here) as we do in the post request.

```
public static final MediaType sparqlGet = MediaType.get("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");

static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    
public static String test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
                 "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\nPREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\nPREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\nSELECT * WHERE {\r\n  ?sub <http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#domainName> ?obj .\r\n}\r\n"
                 , sparqlGet);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://localhost:3030/eduDataSet/query")
                .get()
                .build();
            try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
              return response.body().string();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                return "exc";
            }


    public static String postTest() throws IOException {
    
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\nPREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\r\nPREFIX xx: <http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#>\r\nINSERT DATA{\r\n\t<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#Domain5> xx:domainName \"spring\".\r\n  \t<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/8/untitled-ontology-4#Domain5> xx:domainId \"spring\".\r\n\r\n}\r\n\r\n"
                , sparql);

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url ("http://localhost:3030/eduDataSet/update")
            .post(body)
            .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
          return response.body().string();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return "exc";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A GET doesn't have a request body. So all parameters must appear in the URL or in a header.

Comment: thanks for replying, I understand but what would be the way to execute the query at the other endpoint? I tried to use the post and send the select query to it as a body but as for sure, it gives there's No 'update=' parameter! what would be the solution

Comment: You need to look at the GET API to see what fields it'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to try, even if you can it will be ignored by the server, the only way to send parameters in GET is to use the URL.

Look at the explanation here : https://dropbox.tech/developers/limitations-of-the-get-method-in-http

Comment: thanks for replying, I understand but what would be the way to execute the query at the other endpoint? I tried to use the post and send the select query to it as a body but as for sure, it gives there's No 'update=' parameter! what would be the solution